# Cordova ionic 3 android app Implement Phone auth without Captcha/ReCaptcha

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, ionic3, cordova-plugin-firebasex

i have installed / cordova-plugin-firebase
to send verificationPhone number
my problem is before receiving the sms with OTP code, my app is going background and a chrome page opened and linked to my firebase account and verify "i’am not robot’ … after ~5sec it closes and my app reappear in forground again and i receive an sms containing OTP code.
so, is there away to keep my android app running in forground while opening web page in background.
i don’t want any interruption while waition for the sms.
any help please !
here's my code

```
window.FirebasePlugin.verifyPhoneNumber("my phone number", timeOutDuration, function(credential) {
    console.log(credential);


    firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(signInCredential);
}, function(error) {
    console.error(error);
});
```

here's my android log
D/CordovaActivity: Paused the activity.

> V/FA: Recording user engagement, ms: 41634 V/FA: Connecting to remote
> service W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for
> token android.os.BinderProxy@cbf1c1a D/libMEOW: applied 1 plugins for
> [com.ess.ess]:
> plugin 1: [libMEOW_gift.so]: V/FA: Activity paused, time: 610839869 V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress V/FA:
> onActivityCreated V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 610839913 V/FA:
> Connection attempt already in progress V/FA: Connection attempt
> already in progress W/syndic.essyndi: Accessing hidden method
> Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getInt(Ljava/lang/Object;J)I (greylist, linking,
> allowed)
> Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getObject(Ljava/lang/Object;J)Ljava/lang/Object;
> (greylist, linking, allowed)
> Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getLong(Ljava/lang/Object;J)J
> (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed) W/syndic.essyndi:
> Accessing hidden method
> Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;)V
> (greylist, linking, allowed) W/syndic.essyndi: Accessing hidden method
> Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putInt(Ljava/lang/Object;JI)V (greylist, linking,
> allowed)
> Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putLong(Ljava/lang/Object;JJ)V (greylist, linking,
> allowed) W/syndic.essyndi: Accessing hidden method
> Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getInt(Ljava/lang/Object;J)I (greylist, linking,
> allowed) W/syndic.essyndi: Accessing hidden method
> Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->allocateInstance(Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Object;
> (greylist, linking, allowed) W/syndic.essyndi: Accessing hidden method
> Llibcore/io/Memory;->pokeByte(JB)V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
> Accessing hidden method Llibcore/io/Memory;->peekByte(J)B (greylist, reflection, allowed)
> Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getInt(Ljava/lang/Object;J)I (greylist, linking,
> allowed)
> Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getLong(Ljava/lang/Object;J)J
> (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
> Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getObject(Ljava/lang/Object;J)Ljava/lang/Object;
> (greylist, linking, allowed)
> Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putInt(Ljava/lang/Object;JI)V (greylist, linking,
> allowed)
> Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getLong(Ljava/lang/Object;J)J
> (greylist,core-platform-api, reflection, allowed)
> Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getInt(Ljava/lang/Object;J)I (greylist, reflection,
> allowed)
> Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putInt(Ljava/lang/Object;JI)V (greylist,
> reflection, allowed)
> Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getLong(Ljava/lang/Object;J)J
> (greylist,core-platform-api, reflection, allowed)
> Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putLong(Ljava/lang/Object;JJ)V (greylist,
> reflection, allowed) W/syndic.essyndi: Accessing hidden method
> Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getObject(Ljava/lang/Object;J)Ljava/lang/Object;
> (greylist, reflection, allowed)
> Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;)V
> (greylist, reflection, allowed) W/syndic.essyndi: Accessing hidden
> method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getInt(Ljava/lang/Object;J)I (greylist,
> linking, allowed) W/syndic.essyndi: Accessing hidden method
> Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getObject(Ljava/lang/Object;J)Ljava/lang/Object;
> (greylist, linking, allowed) I/zzdu: keyset not found, will generate a
> new one
> java.io.FileNotFoundException: can't read keyset; the pref value GenericIdpKeyset does not exist
> at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzdy.zzc(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@21.0.1:10)
> at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzdy.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@21.0.1:1)
> at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzaw.zzi(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@21.0.1:1)
> at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzdt.zzi(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@21.0.1:1)
> at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzdt.zzg(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@21.0.1:2)
> at com.google.firebase.auth.internal.zzk.(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@21.0.1:7)
> at com.google.firebase.auth.internal.zzk.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@21.0.1:3)
> at com.google.firebase.auth.internal.RecaptchaActivity.zzb(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@21.0.1:9)
> at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zztr.(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@21.0.1:13)
> at com.google.firebase.auth.internal.RecaptchaActivity.onResume(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@21.0.1:43)
> at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1453)
> at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:7942)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4384)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4429)
> at android.app.servertransaction.ResumeActivityItem.execute(ResumeActivityItem.java:52)
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:181)
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:98)
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2126)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:264)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7684)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:980)
> W/syndic.essyndi: Accessing hidden method
> Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putInt(Ljava/lang/Object;JI)V (greylist, linking,
> allowed)
> Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;)V
> (greylist, linking, allowed) I/zzkp: Provider GmsCore_OpenSSL not
> available W/syndic.essyndi: Accessing hidden method
> Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;)V
> (greylist, linking, allowed) W/syndic.essyndi: Accessing hidden method
> Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putInt(Ljava/lang/Object;JI)V (greylist, linking,
> allowed)
> Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getObject(Ljava/lang/Object;J)Ljava/lang/Object;
> (greylist, linking, allowed) W/syndic.essyndi: Accessing hidden method
> Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putInt(Ljava/lang/Object;JI)V (greylist, linking,
> allowed) W/syndic.essyndi: Accessing hidden method
> Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putInt(Ljava/lang/Object;JI)V (greylist, linking,
> allowed)
> Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;)V
> (greylist, linking, allowed) W/syndic.essyndi: Accessing hidden method
> Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putInt(Ljava/lang/Object;JI)V (greylist, linking,
> allowed)
> Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;)V
> (greylist, linking, allowed) V/PhoneWindow: DecorView setVisiblity:
> visibility = 4, Parent = null, this = DecorView@b238ff6[]
> D/ViewRootImpl[RecaptchaActivity]: hardware acceleration = true ,
> fakeHwAccelerated = false, sRendererDisabled = false,
> forceHwAccelerated = false, sSystemRendererDisabled = false
> I/InputTransport: Create ARC handle: 0x72a0bb2d20 V/PhoneWindow:
> DecorView setVisiblity: visibility = 0, Parent =
> android.view.ViewRootImpl@fff98cd, this =
> DecorView@b238ff6[RecaptchaActivity] W/System: Ignoring header
> X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null. I/System.out:
> [okhttp]:check permission begin!
> [okhttp]:not MMS!
> [okhttp]:not Email! I/System.out: [OkHttp] sendRequest>>
> [OkHttp] sendRequest<< D/Surface: Surface::connect(this=0x720a8df000,api=1) D/mali_winsys: EGLint
> new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display *, void *, EGLSurface,
> EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface **, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000
> D/Surface: Surface::setBufferCount(this=0x720a8df000,bufferCount=3)
> Surface::allocateBuffers(this=0x720a8df000) D/FA: Connected to remote service V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 4 V/FA:
> Screen exposed for less than 1000 ms. Event not sent. time: 460 V/FA:
> Activity paused, time: 610840374 D/Surface:
> Surface::disconnect(this=0x720a8df000,api=1) D/Surface:
> Surface::disconnect(this=0x71b1b7b000,api=1) D/CordovaActivity:
> Stopped the activity. V/PhoneWindow: DecorView setVisiblity:
> visibility = 4, Parent = android.view.ViewRootImpl@1d672fd, this =
> DecorView@c063bf2[MainActivity] V/PhoneWindow: DecorView setVisiblity:
> visibility = 4, Parent = android.view.ViewRootImpl@fff98cd, this =
> DecorView@b238ff6[RecaptchaActivity] I/GED: ged_boost_gpu_freq, level
> 100, eOrigin 2, final_idx 24, oppidx_max 24, oppidx_min 0 D/FA:
> Application going to the background I/BufferQueue:
> SurfaceTexture-0-11798-0
> ~BufferQueueCore W/System: A resource failed to call end.  V/FA:
> Inactivity, disconnecting from the service D/CordovaActivity: Started
> the activity. V/PhoneWindow: DecorView setVisiblity: visibility = 0,
> Parent = android.view.ViewRootImpl@1d672fd, this =
> DecorView@c063bf2[MainActivity] V/FA: Activity resumed, time:
> 610848380 V/FA: Connecting to remote service D/Surface:
> Surface::connect(this=0x71b1b7b000,api=1) D/mali_winsys: EGLint
> new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display *, void *, EGLSurface,
> EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface **, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000
> D/Surface: Surface::setBufferCount(this=0x71b1b7b000,bufferCount=3)
> Surface::allocateBuffers(this=0x71b1b7b000) V/FA: Screen exposed for less than 1000 ms. Event not sent. time: 39
> Connection attempt already in progress
> Activity paused, time: 610848420 D/FA: Connected to remote service D/CordovaActivity: Resumed the activity. V/FA: Processing queued up
> service tasks: 2 V/PhoneWindow: DecorView setVisiblity: visibility =
> 0, Parent = android.view.ViewRootImpl@1d672fd, this =
> DecorView@c063bf2[MainActivity] D/LaunchNavigatorPlugin: Plugin
> action=discoverSupportedApps V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 610848474
> D/NetworkManager: toLower : wifi
> wifi : wifi
> Connection Type: wifi
> Connection Extra Info: null D/PluginManager: postMessage: networkconnection D/View: [Warning] assignParent to null: this =
> DecorView@b238ff6[RecaptchaActivity] I/InputTransport: Destroy ARC
> handle: 0x72a0bb2d20 W/System: Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale
> because its value was null. I/System.out: [okhttp]:check permission
> begin!
> [okhttp]:not MMS!
> [okhttp]:not Email! I/System.out: [OkHttp] sendRequest<< D/FirebasePlugin: success: verifyPhoneNumber.onCodeSent V/FA:
> Inactivity, disconnecting from the service D/CordovaActivity: Paused
> the activity. V/FA: Recording user engagement, ms: 15452 V/FA:
> Connecting to remote service D/CordovaActivity: Stopped the activity.
> V/FA: Activity paused, time: 610863928 I/GED: ged_boost_gpu_freq,
> level 100, eOrigin 2, final_idx 24, oppidx_max 24, oppidx_min 0 V/FA:
> Connection attempt already in progress D/FA: Connected to remote
> service V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 2 D/FA: Application
> going to the background D/Surface:
> Surface::disconnect(this=0x71b1b7b000,api=1) V/PhoneWindow: DecorView
> setVisiblity: visibility = 4, Parent =
> android.view.ViewRootImpl@1d672fd, this =
> DecorView@c063bf2[MainActivity] V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from
> the service W/FirebaseAuth: [SmsRetrieverHelper] Timed out waiting for
> SMS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for anyone who faced the same problem. the solution is  to enable the Android DeviceCheck API for your project and add SHA 256 in your Firebase settings.firebase